# Front end (installed Access 365 32 bit with ODBC MySql BE) won't open for 64 bit users

Tags: ms-access, 32bit-64bit

My development computer has Installed 32-bit Access (Office 365). I now have users with 64-bit Access who cannot open the application. Is there any way to install 64-bit (either Runtime or full) for debugging purposes?  So frustrating!

Comment: Are your users seeing any message when they try to open? What driver are you using to connect to the BE? The driver and access will need to have matching bit-ness.

Comment: Mixed enviroment causes pain, Best to restrict to one bitness. To have both bitnesses for development, use a virtual machine for at least one version. See [MySQL Connector/ODBC Developer Guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/) for x64 config.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your application to 64bit Access
This is done by obtaining a Ms Access 64bit (Office) ..opening your application on it and working out any bitness differences.. and of course providing the appropriate driver for MySQL : https://cdn.mysql.com//Downloads/Connector-ODBC/5.3/mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.14-winx64.msi